# Split two columns into four in sas

Tags: split, sas

I have a table in SAS,

```
Group1   Group2  type
  1.1     1.4     value
  0.5     0.4     value
  5        6      percent
  4        10     percent
```

I want to split this into four columns as follows:

```
Group1_value  Group1_percent Group2_value Group2_percent
 1.1             5               1.4         6
 0.5             4               0.4         10
```

Comment: You can't really do this just with the table you have.  You are missing a column which would be needed to correlate the two rows in your expected output to the source table.

Comment: Answer below should do it, but (@Pari T) is there any reason that you are sorting your `Group2_percent` variable ascending? SAS will default via ascending, hence why `desc` needs to be called in the first 3 queries to output your first 3 variables, but you have your output variable as ascending for `Group2_percent`

Comment: Hi Pari, welcome to the site.  Questions that simply ask to do some work aren't encouraged on this site; to have a well received question, please make some attempt to solve it and show that attempt so we can help you with that rather than simply asking something to be done.  Please see [ask] and the [help] for more information.

Comment: @SMW I think you misuse "sorting" here.  I would assume the rows go together (though clearly there is more information needed), so the 1.1 and 1.4 values are on one line because they're from one observation.  I would guess that there is a missing ID variable here, with values 1,2,1,2 respectively, but again the question really isn't answerable right now, nor should it be.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is `PROC SQL`

This would be quick and dirty.

```
data have;
input group_1 group_2 type $;
cards;
1.1 1.4 value
0.5 0.4 value
5   6   percent
4   10  percent
;
run;

proc sql;
create table g1v as
select distinct group_1 as group1_value
from have
where type = 'value'
order by group_1 desc
;
create table g1p as
select distinct group_1 as group1_percent
from have
where type = 'percent'
order by group_1 desc
;
create table g2v as
select distinct group_2 as group2_value
from have
where type = 'value'
order by group_2 desc
;
create table g2p as
select distinct group_2 as group2_percent
from have
where type = 'percent'
order by group_2
;
data final;
merge g1v g1p g2v g2p;
run;
```

Additional approach is to use the macro facility (but if you only have two values in `type`, then it may not be necessary).

Comment: That's really not something I'd ever encourage someone to do in SAS.  Even if you weren't using `PROC TRANSPOSE`, the data step is going to be better than all that by far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Proc TRANPOSE` after a reshaping the data with a DATA Step.

```
data have;
input 
Group1   Group2  type $; datalines;
  1.1     1.4     value
  0.5     0.4     value
  5        6      percent
  4        10     percent
run;

* reshape data for Proc TRANSPOSE;

data forTranspose;
  set have;
  by type notsorted;
  if first.type then seq = 1; else seq + 1;

  name = 'Group1_' || type;
  value = group1;
  output;

  name = 'Group2_' || type;
  value = group2;
  output;
run;

proc sort data=forTranspose;
  by seq;
run;

proc transpose data=forTranspose out=want;
  by seq;
  id name;
  var value;
run;
```